# @Url.Action results 404 error when called from form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, get, model-binding

I work on ASP.NET MVC application. Table is being populated using jQuery, but it doesn't matter now.

The problem is this:
When I make a call with form tags, I get an error 404 Not Found. By inspecting I confirmed that model is bound OK (it's populated).

When I comment out form tags, I can make a call to method, but  with model being null (like it's not bound).

Here is some of code I use:

```
@model  PayrollModel

@*@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Request", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmPersonView" }))
{*@

    <table data-dataurl="@Url.Action("PayrollData", "Payroll")" id="tblData" class="table hover table-bordered table-striped"></table>
@*}*@
```

Here is my controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult PayrollData(PayrollModel model)
{
    //do something
}
```

**Edited:**
I found out why this happens:
Request URL:

http:// localhost/CT.ISVDV.WebUI/Payroll/PayrollData?sEcho=1&iColumns=5&sColumns=&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=10&mDataProp_0=FIRSTNAME&mDataProp_1=LASTNAME&mDataProp_2=RIGHTGROUPNAME&mDataProp_3=DISABILITYTYPENAME&mDataProp_4=AMOUNT&iSortCol_0=0&sSortDir_0=asc&iSortingCols=1&bSortable_0=true&bSortable_1=true&bSortable_2=true&bSortable_3=true&bSortable_4=true&SelectedTypes%5B3%5D=4&SelectedTypes%5B4%5D=5&SelectedTypes%5B5%5D=6&SelectedTypes%5B6%5D=7&SelectedTypes%5B7%5D=8&SelectedTypes%5B8%5D=9&SelectedTypes%5B9%5D=10&SelectedTypes%5B10%5D=11&SelectedTypes%5B11%5D=12&SelectedTypes%5B12%5D=13&SelectedTypes%5B13%5D=14&SelectedTypes%5B14%5D=15&SelectedTypes%5B15%5D=16&SelectedTypes%5B16%5D=17&SelectedTypes%5B17%5D=18&SelectedTypes%5B18%5D=19&SelectedTypes%5B19%5D=20&SelectedTypes%5B20%5D=21&SelectedTypes%5B21%5D=22&SelectedTypes%5B22%5D=23&SelectedTypes%5B23%5D=24&SelectedTypes%5B24%5D=25&SelectedTypes%5B25%5D=26&PayrollDate=01.12.2014&PayrollSearch.RIGHTGROUPIDList.Value%5B0%5D=4&PayrollSearch.RIGHTGROUPIDList.Value%5B1%5D=5&PayrollSearch.RIGHTGROUPIDList.Value%5B2%5D=6&PayrollSearch.RIGHTGROUPIDList.Value%5B3%5D=7&PayrollSearch.RIGHTGROUPIDList.Value%5B4%5D=8&PayrollSearch.RIGHTGROUPIDList.Value%5B5%5D=9&PayrollSearch.RIGHTGROUPIDList.Value%5B6%5D=10&PayrollSearch.RIGHTGROUPIDList.Value%5B7%5D=11&PayrollSearch.RIGHTGROUPIDList.Value%5B8%5D=12&PayrollSearch.RIGHTGROUPIDList.Value%5B9%5D=13&PayrollSearch.RIGHTGROUPIDList.Value%5B10%5D=14&PayrollSearch.RIGHTGROUPIDList.Value%5B11%5D=15&PayrollSearch.RIGHTGROUPIDList.Value%5B12%5D=16&PayrollSearch.RIGHTGROUPIDList.Value%5B13%5D=17&PayrollSearch.RIGHTGROUPIDList.Value%5B14%5D=18&PayrollSearch.RIGHTGROUPIDList.Value%5B15%5D=19&PayrollSearch.RIGHTGROUPIDList.Value%5B16%5D=20&PayrollSearch.RIGHTGROUPIDList.Value%5B17%5D=21&PayrollSearch.RIGHTGROUPIDList.Value%5B18%5D=22&PayrollSearch.RIGHTGROUPIDList.Value%5B19%5D=23&PayrollSearch.RIGHTGROUPIDList.Value%5B20%5D=24&PayrollSearch.RIGHTGROUPIDList.Value%5B21%5D=25&PayrollSearch.RIGHTGROUPIDList.Value%5B22%5D=26&tblData_length=10&

**Up to this point, everything is right, but then  i also passes some strange values that are not model properties. This happens only if I  use form tags, and I need those.**

DXScript=1_157%2C1_89%2C1_88%2C17_28%2C17_2%2C1_149%2C1_86%2C1_141%2C1_96%2C17_7%2C1_139%2C1_98%2C1_97%2C17_8%2C1_155%2C1_125%2C1_156%2C1_118%2C17_9%2C1_148%2C1_147%2C1_132%2C17_27%2C1_142%2C1_93%2C1_119%2C1_99%2C1_151%2C1_126%2C17_13%2C1_108%2C1_115%2C1_137%2C1_92%2C1_152%2C1_128%2C17_15%2C1_129%2C1_120%2C17_11%2C1_131%2C1_140%2C1_134%2C17_18%2C1_145%2C17_20%2C1_143%2C1_138%2C1_146%2C1_150%2C17_23%2C17_26%2C1_95%2C5_5%2C5_4%2C4_11%2C4_10%2C4_6%2C4_7%2C4_9%2C17_14%2C4_12%2C1_107%2C1_110%2C4_13%2C4_14%2C1_106%2C1_124%2C17_12%2C1_144%2C7_48%2C1_91%2C7_50%2C17_19%2C1_100%2C1_103%2C1_111%2C17_0%2C1_114%2C1_101%2C17_1%2C1_102%2C17_3%2C1_104%2C1_116%2C17_5%2C1_130%2C1_113%2C17_16%2C17_17%2C1_112%2C17_24%2C1_117%2C10_2%2C10_1%2C10_3%2C10_4%2C17_4%2C9_15%2C9_12%2C9_10%2C17_21%2C9_14%2C9_11%2C9_13%2C8_10%2C8_17%2C8_24%2C8_26%2C8_9%2C8_12%2C8_13%2C8_18%2C17_22%2C8_21%2C8_23%2C8_22%2C8_16%2C8_19%2C8_20%2C8_14%2C8_15%2C8_25%2C8_11%2C6_12%2C17_25&DXCss=%2FCT.ISVDV.WebUI%2Fimg%2Ffavicon.ico%2C%2FCT.ISVDV.WebUI%2FContent%2Fjvectormap%2Fjquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css%2C%2FCT.ISVDV.WebUI%2FContent%2Fbootstrap.min.css%2C%2FCT.ISVDV.WebUI%2FContent%2Ffont-awesome.min.css%2C%2FCT.ISVDV.WebUI%2FContent%2Fionicons.min.css%2C%2FCT.ISVDV.WebUI%2FContent%2FiCheck%2Fall.css%2C%2FCT.ISVDV.WebUI%2FContent%2Fcolorpicker%2Fbootstrap-colorpicker.min.css%2C%2FCT.ISVDV.WebUI%2FContent%2Ftimepicker%2Fbootstrap-timepicker.min.css%2C%2FCT.ISVDV.WebUI%2FContent%2Fmorris%2Fmorris.css%2C%2FCT.ISVDV.WebUI%2FContent%2Fdatepicker%2Fdatepicker3.css%2C%2FCT.ISVDV.WebUI%2FContent%2Fdaterangepicker%2Fdaterangepicker-bs3.css%2C%2FCT.ISVDV.WebUI%2FContent%2Fbootstrap-wysihtml5%2Fbootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css%2C%2FCT.ISVDV.WebUI%2FContent%2Fcss%2Fselect2.css%2C%2FCT.ISVDV.WebUI%2FContent%2Fselect2-bootstrap.css%2C%2FCT.ISVDV.WebUI%2FContent%2Fdatatables%2FdataTables.bootstrap.css%2C%2FCT.ISVDV.WebUI%2FContent%2FAdminLTE.css%2C%2FCT.ISVDV.WebUI%2FContent%2FSite.css%2C%2FCT.ISVDV.WebUI%2FContent%2Fjquery.bootstrap-touchspin%2Fjquery.bootstrap-touchspin.css%2C1_9%2C1_11%2C0_844%2C0_842%2C1_8%2C0_691%2C0_694%2C0_682%2C1_4%2C0_684%2C0_805%2C0_698%2C4_2%2C0_700%2C5_1%2C0_782%2C0_762%2C0_764%2C7_1%2C7_0%2C1_1%2C0_657%2C0_869%2C0_871%2C0_777%2C8_2%2C0_779%2C8_0%2C0_794%2C6_2%2C0_796&_=1417596051723

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: What are you trying to do??

Comment: Just to parse some Json data returned from Payroll/PayrollData method. This is a JQuery table control,  which works this way.

Comment: This way model will not get posted

Comment: I edited my question, please look it up.

Answer (score 0):

Your formatting is off. Try mix single quotes with double ones:

```
data-dataurl='@Url.Action("PayrollData", "Payroll")'
```

PayrollData expects a PayrollModel model and you're providing none. There's no reasonable way to send a whole model using `Url.Action` so consider sending only an ID.

```
data-dataurl='@Url.Action("PayrollData", "Payroll", new { id = model.ID })'
```

Comment: uncommented form tags and tried that, but without succes

Comment: PayrollData expects a PayrollModel model and you're providing none. There's no reasonable way to send a whole model using Url.Action so consider sending only an ID.

Comment: Wouldn't including form tags provide a model for PayrollData action? Even with explicit passing, I get the same error. I can't pass id only, as I use populated model atributes for queryes on database.

Comment: Url.Action is not submitting the form, it's just fetching a url. The form get's submitted to Action Index of Controller Request when you trigger a form submit.

Comment: @Mihai-AndreiDinculescu, You can send a whole model if the model contains only properties which are value types (that the purpose of the overload which accepts `object` - internally it creates a route value dictionary from the objects properties). That said, what OP is doing makes no sense anyway

Comment: I looked up - then I wished I never did. Please edit your formatting and remove the clutter :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are very confused on how it all works, especially model binding.

Normally you would have something like this (Lets say we are working only have Payroll controller)

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
 // here you would get your model that displays some data on that page
 PayrollIndexModel model = fetchModelData(); 
 return View(model)
}
```

and its view

```
@model  PayrollIndexModel
@Model.PageTitle    
@using (Html.BeginForm("Request", "Payroll", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmPersonView" }))
{
     <table data-dataurl="@Url.Action("PayrollData", "Payroll")" id="tblData" class="table hover table-bordered table-striped"></table>         
}
```

then if you click Save on the form you would call the one below where PayrollModel is binded to your model class and later you can do things with it.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Request(PayrollModel model)
{
  // save stuff to database
}
```

To get this one working

```
@Url.Action("PayrollData", "Payroll")
```

You have to create actions this way as you are requesting data by GET method and not sending anything to the server:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult PayrollData()
{
 PayrollModel model = fetchModelData();
 return View(model)
}
```

However, I see that you use DataTables library and last time I used it I remember that Datatable is expecting JSON object. So here you should send JSON.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult PayrollData()
{
 PayrollModel model = fetchModelData(); 
 return Json(model)
}
```

Your model converted to JSON should be formatted in the way that JQuery DataTable can parse it (understand it) such as:

```
{ "iTotalRecords":11,
"iTotalDisplayRecords":11,
"sEcho":1,
"aaData":[{"FirstName":"Dan","LastName":"Callahan","PhoneNumber":"(123) 555-5552","Age":35,"Birthday":"\/Date(218955600000)\/"},
{"FirstName":"Tom","LastName":"Gun","PhoneNumber":"(123) 555-5559","Age":59,"Birthday":"\/Date(-534538800000)\/"},
{"FirstName":"James","LastName":"Halk","PhoneNumber":"(123) 555-5554","Age":21,"Birthday":"\/Date(660027600000)\/"},
{"FirstName":"Jarold","LastName":"Interface","PhoneNumber":"(123) 555-5556","Age":39,"Birthday":"\/Date(86932800000)\/"},
{"FirstName":"Kevin","LastName":"Kentucky","PhoneNumber":"(123) 555-5551","Age":40,"Birthday":"\/Date(92638800000)\/"},
{"FirstName":"Justin","LastName":"Michaels","PhoneNumber":"(123) 555-5555","Age":27,"Birthday":"\/Date(470898000000)\/"},
{"FirstName":"Erich","LastName":"Milton","PhoneNumber":"(123) 555-5558","Age":54,"Birthday":"\/Date(-370724400000)\/"},
{"FirstName":"Mike","LastName":"Peterson","PhoneNumber":"(123) 555-5550","Age":24,"Birthday":"\/Date(568184400000)\/"},
{"FirstName":"Jason","LastName":"Ralph","PhoneNumber":"(123) 555-5557","Age":27,"Birthday":"\/Date(468306000000)\/"},
{"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Thompson21","PhoneNumber":"(123) 555-5545","Age":27,"Birthday":"\/Date(473317200000)\/"}
]}
```

To make your life easier check this library which does a lot of tedious work for you: 
https://github.com/ALMMa/datatables.mvc

Good Luck.